# sample of a subsample

Tags: r, sample, tibble, createsamples

I would like to select a sample from a dataset twice. Actually, I don't want to select it, but to create a new variable `sampleNo` that indicates to which sample (one or two) a case belongs to.

Lets suppose I have a dataset containing 40 cases:

```
data <- data.frame(var1=seq(1:40), var2=seq(40,1))
```

The first sample (n=10) I drew like this:

```
data$sampleNo <- 0
idx <- sample(seq(1,nrow(data)), size=10, replace=F)
data[idx,]$sampleNo <- 1
```

Now, (and here my problems start) I'd like to draw a second sample (n=10). But this sample should be drawn from the cases that don't belong to the first sample only. **Additionally, "var1" should be an even number.**

So `sampleNo` should be 0 for cases that were not drawn at all, 1 for cases that belong to the first sample and 2 for cases belonging to the second sample (= `sampleNo` equals 0 and `var1` is even).

I was trying to solve it like this:

```
idx2<-data$var1%%2 & data$sampleNo==0
sample(data[idx2,], size=10, replace=F)
```

But how can I set `sampleNo` to 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete solution to your problem more along the line of your original idea. The code can be shortened but for now I tried to make it as transparent as I could.

```
# Data
data <- data.frame(var1 = 1:40, var2 = 40:1) 

# Add SampleNo column
data$sampleNo <- 0L

# Randomly select 10 rows as sample 1
pool_idx1 <- 1:nrow(data)
idx1 <- sample(pool_idx1, size = 10)
data[idx1, ]$sampleNo <- 1L

# Draw a second sample from cases where sampleNo != 1 & var1 is even 
pool_idx2 <- pool_idx1[data$var1 %% 2 == 0 & data$sampleNo != 1]
idx2 <- sample(pool_idx2, size = 10)
data[idx2, ]$sampleNo <- 2L
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use the [`setdiff`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/prob/versions/0.9-1/topics/setdiff) function as follows:

```
sample(setdiff(1:nrow(data), idx), 3, replace = F)
```

`setdiff(x, y)` will select the elements of `x` that are not in `y`:

```
setdiff(x = 1:20, y = seq(2,20,2))
 [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

---

So to include in the above example:

```
data$sampleNo2 <- 0
idx2 <- sample(setdiff(1:nrow(data), idx), 3, replace = F)
data[idx2,]$sampleNo2 <- 1
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: And what if I wanted to add another condition when drawing the second sample? Let's say that the second sample should only be drawn where sampleNo!=0 **AND var1 is an odd number**?

Comment: `seq(2, x, 2)` will generate the even numbers you wish to exclude, you could just wrap it in `setdiff` (I'm sure there are a few other ways, too) `setdiff(setdiff(1:nrow(data), idx), seq(2, nrow(data), 2))`

Comment: But your suggestion only accounts for the odd numbers, not for the first condition (sampleNo==0) too. I tried to use idx<-data$sampleNo==1 & data$var1%%2 when using the second sample-function